# Qt Jambi vs JOGL for java OpenGL development?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, qt-jambi

I'm planning on writing a simple application in Java which has a basic UI with a section of OpenGL graphics. In addition to this some kind of network access is required.

Which one of these libraries should I use? What are the drawbacks and benefits of each option? I'd like the OpenGL coding be as genuine as possible, so that I could feel that I'm actually (learning) coding OpenGL. Is the surrounding UI significantly easier to code with one of the solutions? In the case of JOGL I'll propably make the UI with standard java components.

Just give some thoughts for me to thinker on, I'm not searching for the ultimate truth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Qt Jambi is discontinued](http://qt.nokia.com/about/news/preview-of-final-qt-jambi-release-available), so I would go JOGL just for this reason.

Also if your intent is just to have just a few basic controls on top of your 3d scene, I suggest you learn about IMGUI (Immediate Mode GUI) [here](https://mollyrocket.com/forums/viewforum.php?f=10) and [there](http://sol.gfxile.net/imgui/).

Although it's not Java, [NVIDIA made available IMGUI based widgets](http://code.google.com/p/nvidia-widgets/) from which you can get inspiration.

Comment: Ah, hadn't noticed that press release. Well, not much to thinker about then. Thank's for the heads up!

Comment: From the press release: *"To help faciliate the continued development of Qt Jambi, Qt Software will host and help maintain a community-driven Qt Jambi implementation."* Qt-Jambi is still under active community development and at release 4.7.1 beta 3. See http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-jambi/pages/Home for information, and if you check their repositories, notice that someone committed to qtjambi-community.git just yesterday.

Comment: I realize this answer is old, but I thought I'd provide an update for anyone who stumbles across and thinks Qt Jambi is dead.

Answer (score 1):

JOGL has [JMonkeyEngine](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/) .. a pretty nice game engine. I would recommend JOGL since it is pretty cross platform, soon with embedded platform implementations.

Comment: Nice to know that too, although I'm not needing a full graphics/game engine at this time with this particular project.